# How do I convert Price (formated as "$xx.xx")into numeric format without creating a lot of nas?

Tags: r

I am working on a dataset that has 2 Price formatted variables that are currently read as character format. I need them to be numerical. I have tried the following different examples but all have created more than a thousand nas when I run it.

```
dataframe$Price <-as.numeric(dataframe$Price)
dataframe$Price <-as.numeric(as.character(dataframe$Price))
```

If I run it as

```
as.numeric(dataframe$Price)
```

It doesn't change the variable. I am relatively new to R (about 2 months) and I have no idea what I'm doing. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you post a reproducible sample of the data using `dput(head(dataframe, 10))`?

Comment: As a note, Rstudio is a text editor for R, often referred to as an "IDE" (integrated development environment). It is not a different programming language from R, but has a symbiotic relationship with R.

Answer (score 2):

If every elements of `dataframe$Price` is like `$12.12`, for example,

```
dummy <- data.frame(
  Price = c("$12.11", "$11.14", "$10.12")
)

   Price
1 $12.11
2 $11.14
3 $10.12
```

By using `stringr::str_replace` function,

```
dummy$Price <- as.numeric(str_replace(dummy$Price, "\\$", ""))

  Price
1 12.11
2 11.14
3 10.12
```